# How can I get first 5 and last 1 records from table mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on php small project, here I need first 5 records from beginning of records and last record 1 from end of the table's record. I don't know how to write a single mysqli query.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: checkout the UNION keyword to join the results of two SQL queries into one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  So, there is no such thing as the first five rows or last row -- unless a column explicitly defines the ordering.

Often, a table has some sort of auto-incremented id column, which can be used for this purpose.  If so, you can do:

```
(select t.*
 from t
 order by id asc
 limit 5
) union all
(select t.*
 from t
 order by id desc
 limit 1
);
```

Notes:

- Sometimes, an insert date/time column is the appropriate column to use.
- You want to use `union all` rather than `union` -- unless you want to incur the overhead of removing duplicate values.
- For this formulation, if there are fewer than 6 rows, then you will get a duplicate.

Comment: Great answer. I didn't know about UNION ALL and the dupes problem.

Comment: Hey @Gordon Linoff what about duplicate records when there are only five records in table than the query result first five records than the last one record is five also included in the query result?

Comment: @UmarShahzad . .  If you want six records then use `UNION ALL`.  If you want five records, then use `UNION`.

Answer (score 5):

The UNION operator allows this, carefully toying with the ORDER BY and LIMIT clauses :

```
(SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY field ASC LIMIT 5)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY field DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: yw, but I suggest you accept @Gordon Linoff's answer below, he's done a good job at explaining the specifics and benefits of UNION ALL, if that's relevant to your case :-)